# .Net SyndicationFeed serialization error when adding extensions to the RSS feed

Tags: c#, .net, rss, xml-serialization, syndicationfeed

I create a .NET Framework SyndicationFeed:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
```

Then I create a new item:

```
var newItem = new SyndicationItem();
newItem.Id = sourceFeedItem.ItemID;
newItem.Title = new TextSyndicationContent(sourceFeedItem.ItemTitle);
```

Then I add some iTunes item extensions:

```
var iTunesExt = newItem.ElementExtensions;
iTunesExt.Add(new XElement("MyElement", "Whatever");
newItem.ElementExtensions.Add(iTunesExt);
```

Then I add the item to the `items` list:

```
List<SyndicationItem> items = new List<SyndicationItem>();
items.Add(newItem);
```

and set the feed's `Items` property.

```
feed.Items = items;
```

and finally I write the `SyndicationFeed` `feed` to an `XmlWriter`.

```
feed.SaveAsRss20(xmlWriter);
```

All goes well if the extensions *aren't* added, in other words if the `newItem.ElementExtensions.Add(iTunesExt);` line doesn't execute.  But if the line executes, I get the following error upon execution of `feed.SaveAsRss20(xmlWriter);`.

> Type 'System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationElementExtension'
>   cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the
>   DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you
>   want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type
>   is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.

How can I mark `iTunesExt` with the `DataContractAttribute` attribute?  Or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 0):

```
iTunesExt.Add(new XElement("MyElement", "Whatever");
```

Try modifying this to:

```
iTunesExt.Add(new XElement("MyElement", "Whatever"), 
    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(XElement)));
```

That allows you to specify use of the `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: what I get now is `"An object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XNodeReader' cannot be serialized at the top level for IXmlSerializable root type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' since its IsAny setting is 'true'. This type must write all its contents including the root element. Verify that the IXmlSerializable implementation is correct."`.  I'm going to do some further resource because I'm not totally clear I even understand the errors yet.